# How enable/implement Multi Threading in the WSGIServer of Flask Python

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, wsgiserver

I have a Flask API which servers to Web and Mobile Apps.
But sometimes on heavy load, app or websites stop quick response and displays results taking time, 
**I just want to enable multithreading in the flask running with WSGIServer.**

```
def main():
"""Main entry point of the app."""
try:
    http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8084), app, log=logging, error_log=logging)
    http_server.serve_forever()
except Exception as exc:
    logger.error(exc.message)
    logger.exception(traceback.format_exc())
finally:
    # Do something here
    pass
```

Thanks,

Comment: Flask does not include a `WSGIServer`. You must be importing `WSGIServer` from somewhere else — where?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in Flask development server, whilst not intended for multithreaded use *or* deployment does allow multithreading:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

The above code is a simple Hello World script that uses multithreading; not that any process is using another thread, but you get the idea.